# Split UpperCamelCase and UPPERCamelCase to separate words

Tags: python, regex

What I am trying to do is to split UpperCamelCase and UPPERCamelCase strings into different words. We have naming convention in which abbreviations are written in UPPERCASE if in the beginning.

Eg. `SFTPServer`

What I am trying to accomplish is split this into two words `SFTP` and `Server`

For UpperCamelCase I was able to use the following piece of code

```
r="SftpServer"
print(' '.join(re.findall('^[a-z]+|[A-Z][^A-Z]*', r)))
```

*Outputs:*

```
Sftp Server
```

*Question:*  Is there some way to tweak this regex so that I will get output for both cases

ie. `SFTPServer` and `SftpServer`?

I will also mention my use case as it may further provide some insight into the question.
I am trying to convert column names into labels in flask and SQL Server.

```
def get_label_names():
        cursor=CONN.cursor()
        db_name=CONFIG['DB']['DATABASE']['NAME']
        cursor.execute('use '+db_name)
        cursor.execute(f"""\
        SELECT COLUMN_NAME
        FROM {db_name}.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
        WHERE TABLE_NAME = N'Client'
        """
        )
        col_info=[item[0] for item in cursor.fetchall()]
        labels=[' '.join(re.findall('^[a-z]+|[A-Z][^A-Z]*', r)) for r in col_info]
        return labels
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Our best option here is probably `re.findall`, because it allows using lookaheads, while `re.split` does not.  We can try splitting on 
te following pattern:

```
[A-Z]{2,}(?=[A-Z][a-z])|[A-Z][a-z]+|[A-Z]+$
```

This pattern says to match:

```
[A-Z]{2,}(?=[A-Z][a-z])
```

Two or more uppercase letters, until reaching an uppercase followed by a lowercase (indicating the start of a the next camelcase word).

```
[A-Z][a-z]+
```

A camelcase word, given by an uppercase followed by one or more lowercase letters.

```
[A-Z]+$
```

Any number of terminal uppercase letters in succession.

Code:

```
input = "SFTPServerABC"
results = re.findall(r'[A-Z]{2,}(?=[A-Z][a-z])|[A-Z][a-z]+|[A-Z]+$', input)
print(results)

['SFTP', 'Server', 'ABC']
```